# MongoDB: Does Write Concern guarantee the write on primary plus atleast one secondary

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting push back from few team members in using MongoDB for a project because of the issues raised in the blog http://aphyr.com/posts/284-call-me-maybe-mongodb regarding write concern. Appreciate if someone can confirm if the issues are addressed in Mongo 2.6 release. On a parallel note, if I have a primary with 2 secondaries,  is it possible to make sure one of the secondaries is a mirror of primary (meaning no data loss when I failed over) using tag set?

Comment: How to configure replica-sets is a question for database administrators, not for software developers. For that reason you should ask this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Philipp this is a dev architecture question. Please don't keep asking to routing questions to other sites.

Comment: I am trying to help you to get the best answer possible. You will usually get the best answers when you post on the stackexchange site where your question is most on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I want to answer this here since I am actually reading the article as I answer this:

> “Revert” certainly doesn't sound like linearizability to me,

Uh, what else is it supposed to do? Also it doesn't truly revert, it stores the data in binary files for later application, are you saying that in the 1 in a 1,000,000th case your network is naturally going to die in this manner on a replica set acked you wish to punish because MongoDB does not know if the writes recieved by that primary are still upto date?

BAD MONGODB! SPANK YA HARD!

> Clients for MongoDB didn't bother to check whether or not their writes succeeded

That post was written after all drivers had been converted to acknowledged writes...

> they just sent them and assumed everything went fine.

Good to note this no longer truly exists in MongoDB, it has actually been removed. Unacknowledged means something else in 2.6.

> This goes about as well as you'd expect.

Your doing it wrong, you are expecting consistency from this, that was never the point of unacknowledged. Unackowleged was about sending fast, forgettable writes to MongoDB.

> 42% write loss

You don't say, I know here is a great plan I will throw wites to `/dev/null` and assume they should all stick...

> Well, theoretically. In my tests, it only does this in 1 out of 5 runs or so. Mostly, it just throws those writes away entirely: no rollback files, no nothing. I don't really know why.

Have you tried reporting the issue? That might help...personally I have not had this experience.

> We can still get conflicting writes if the old primary's state is causally unconnected from the new primary.

Again unacknowledged writes can cause that.

> A primary/secondary system, by itself, is not sufficient.

WTF! The documentation states you should have three members...try reading it!

> Otherwise, newly elected primaries could diverge from the old one.

Yea, how else can it be done? I mean I can't see into the future with 100% certainty; can you?

> Aha! But that was with the old “unsafe” write concern! We should use the Safe write concern!

You should have checked what your application said about those writes, MongoDB leaves resending and rewriting upto the application. A very sane approach in my view.

> We need to make sure that the replicas have received our write before considering it a success.

Or you can try using something called EXCEPTIONS.

> Mongo still dropped two “successful” writes.

Again did you check to see what the application said, these writes were most likely returned back to the application during election.

> The client sees the “OK” message and… sensibly presumes the write was OK.

Edge cases do exist, it is sometimes very difficult for them not to, networks are impossibly conplicated like that.

I wouldn't mind having a JIRA link to that bug personally so I can see.

> those failed writes could materialize never, now, or some time in the future; potentially overwriting valid data.

I mean you can easily have a failure back from the set but the wite succeeds since within that nanosecond window the disk was commited but the server failed before it could return a response, welcome to the world of networks buddy!

And, no, they will occur in the order and palce you said for them to, you just got the sever at that split brain moment.

As explained by the very first comment:

> Actually, this can happen in any kind of cluster. In fact, it can happen even in single server failure. It simply means that there is a short moment where data is committed (to disk, to a cluster… any definition of committed) but acknowledgement of this has not yet been sent back to client, at which point the server (or client) crashes. So the commit has happened properly, you just didn’t hear about it.

Rule number one: Networks are unreliable.

> Then I talk to Mongo users who report their cluster fails over on a weekly basis.

You do?

> like seasonal writes

What a crap network you have.

> Conflicts in capped collections, for example, appear to simply discard all data in the collection past the conflict point by design.

I cannot seem to find reference on that, I will need to test it at some point, I personally don't use capped collections. Not even for queues. However:

> People use capped collections for distributed queues. Think about that for a minute.

My queues can actually deal with a lost write. For example I have a cloud video encoder which encodes all my videos for a video site (like YouTube) and that picks out all videos from my collection which have not been encoded, queues them for encoding which then it picks from and sends the video to be encoded. No matter what happens my queue will survive.

Anyway back to your question:

> Appreciate if someone can confirm if the issues are addressed in Mongo 2.6 release.

I am unsure since there is only really one problem from what I can see, if it is a problem that can even be solved in a distributed network setup which is the acked wites that do not exist.

Since he does not care to reference a bug it is quite hard for me to say whether, in the tests he uses, the bug has been fixed.

> On a parallel note, if I have a primary with 2 secondaries, is it possible to make sure one of the secondaries is a mirror of primary (meaning no data loss when I failed over) using tag set?

Use an ACID database. Problem solved...well, not quite even MySQL and other techs are not safe from these problems:

- http://alexalexander.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/mysql-replication-inconsistencies-are.html
- http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/15/crash-resistant-replication-how-to-avoid-mysql-replication-errors/

To show a few.

Comment: I would like to add to set the write concern as of version 2.4.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg good good I spent too much time just explaining networks to say anything else :)

Answer (score 3):

Beside seconding the excellent analysis of @Sammaye , I would like to add that the issue can easily be dealt with: do a read back! This technique precedes MongoDB by decades, as I might add.

#### How to do it

If your data is so valuable that you must be absolutely positively sure that it has made it to at least one of the secondaries, you can take the following approach:

1. Use a write concern with `w > 1` or even better `{w:"majority"}` (BTW: You *can* [make this the default behaviour](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#modify-default-write-concern))
2. Set the write concern option `{fsync:true}` **instead** of `{j:true}`, which actually makes the driver wait until the the data is written to the datafile.
3. After your write statement returned, query for the data with the [read preference set to `secondary`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#read-preference-reference). Note that unless you set the write concern to 'all' (which will cause a fail during the write operation when one data bearing node of the replica set is down), this read operation still may return stale data as it might read from a secondary which has not been in the majority pool. Wait and repeat as you see fit for your use case.
4. Throw and handle an exception in case you can not positively confirm that the data has been written to all data bearing nodes.

#### The Pros

With this technique, you can be sure that the data is written to the primary and at least one secondary and can safely assume that the data is written to the number of nodes chosen in the write concern setting *at least*. That is pretty granular control over a cluster, though it is to be admitted that [Cassandra provides a similar mechanism](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) and most likely HBase does, too.

#### The Cons

This procedure won't be fast. Expect it to be orders of magnitude slower that a write operation with `{w:'majority'},{j:true}`, which should be sufficient for 99.999% of the use cases.

#### When to use

Use this procedure for data which is both *extremely* valuable (because you hardware requirements for scaling will be much higher) and (almost) impossible to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the pattern. I'm also posting the response from MongoDB for the blog post https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15153